# python twitter public stream stops after some time

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to get tweets from the following public stream using twitter module of python 2.7

> https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json

I create a stream iterable as follows:

```
tweet_iter = stream.statuses.filter(track = "social")
```

and here is my iteration of tweets:

```
for tweet in tweet_iter: 
    print tweet
```

The problem is that it only returns a few tweets and stops returning. It just waits. When I kill the script and restart again it returns different set of tweets and stops again. There is not any continuous stream of tweets. I tried different tracking filters but it always behaves the same. Is this normal?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when it stops returning or does just hang there forever? My stream often waits because no one is actually tweeting at that time.

Comment: It appeared that, it was because of the fact that twitter servers were overloaded. I haven't changed anything and it is working normally, now.

Comment: That's good to hear :), maybe you should answer your own question so other people can benefit from it :).